# Confusion about file.cs name, class name

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest

So I am following [a tutorial](http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/Services/WebServices.htm) to send JSON data to SQL using WCF Service.

Let's say the project is named JsonWcfService.

Inside this project there's a .cs file named `Order.cs` added:

```
namespace JsonWcfService
{
    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public class wsOrder
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int OrderID { get; set; }

        //some other fields
    }
}
```

As you can see, file name and class name are different.

Then, there is function using this class, to deserialize Json data sent, accepting `Stream JSONDataStream` as parameter:

```
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(JSONDataStream);
string JSONData = stream.ReadToEnd();

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
wsOrder order = jss.Deserialize<wsOrder>(JSONData);
```

So here the data is deserialized into a single instance of wsOrder class (if I understand that correctly).

Next, we see if there's a record matching our OrderID inside the database:

```
testDBDataContext dc = new testDBDataContext();
Order currentOrder = dc.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderID == order.OrderID).FirstOrDefault();
```

And here's my confusion: `Order currentOrder` - does it say it is an instance of Order.cs file? Is this a namespace?

When I try to write my own WCF service, and create a `Example.cs` with `public class wsExample` inside, it gives me the following error:

`The type or namespace name 'Example' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

when I try to use the same method as described above:

```
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(testData);
string testReceive = stream.ReadToEnd();

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
wsExample example = jss.Deserialize<wsExample>(testReceive);

testDBDataContext dc = new testDBDataContext();
Example currentExample = dc.testTable.Where(o => o.name == example.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that `Order` is either a typo, or it is a type in the EntityFramework generated database context. If it is the latter, there should be some mapping from `wsOrder` to `Order` and vice versa.

I isn't the 'name-of-a-file-as-a-class'. C# doesn't do that. You can have multiple classes in one file and one class can be spread over multiple files (using `partial`). But it doesn't derive class names from files.

Comment: I mean the example provided in the tutorial works, but when I try to copy it myself following the steps it doesn't and throws the error. When I hover over the `Order` in VS, it says `Class JsonWcfService.Order`. I'm now thinking, maybe VS automatically generates some class when you attach database connection to it?

Comment: Yes, I guess it uses EF Database First to generate the code files. What happens if you hit F12 on `Order`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that shortcut. It points to a partial class named order in the database designer.cs file. I guess that's the class I'm looking for.

Comment: Indeed. So it is generated from EF.

Comment: Well, I'm using the `Add item: LINQ to SQL class` but I guess it genereates the same, thanks!